# Script that updates Mercurial repos to the version with a specific label

Tags: mercurial

We automate pulling from a remote repository and do the customary Post-Pull Update. In a couple of cases, we'd like the repository to update not to the `tip`, but to a node with a specific label (tag).

Did I miss an obvious option?  Any thoughts?

Comment: hg update -r <tag name> doesn't do this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that `hg update --rev <tag name>` should do the trick for you.

Comment: yep, seems to be true; we thought -r only took a revision number

Comment: `-r|--rev` is optional as well.  `REV` can be specified many ways.  See `hg help revisions`.